# java composition

Tags: java, oop

I'm trying to use and learn the  **composition's relation between classes respecting the flexibility of OOP programming**, a small sample code that explains what I'm trying to do:

Main class:

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

private Test test;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new MainFrame();    
  }

public MainFrame() {
    initFrame();
    }  

private void initFrame() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(100,100);
    setResizable(false);
    setUndecorated(true);
    setVisible(true);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    test.update();

    }
    public void setNumber(int i) {
    System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

and this class:

```
public class Test {
MainFrame mainFrame;
public void update(){
    mainFrame.setNumber(10);
  }

}
```

if i run this i will get :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

how can I change the code so that:

- The `Test` class refers only to the `MainFrame` instance created in the `main`, not to create a new instance of the `MainFrame` inside the `Test` class
- It is possible to avoid the use of static classes and static functions to do this?

Comment: The main cause of this exception is you are not creating the object of the class `MainFrame`  inside `Test`.Pass the MainFrame object to Test class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The Test class refers only to the MainFrame instance created in the
>   main, not to create a new instance of the MainFrame inside the Test
>   class

Sorry, this makes no sense.  That's not how Java works, and the runtime is educating you.

This code is wrong from top to bottom.

The instance in the `Test` class is null because you never initialized it.

The `Test` class knows nothing about the main method in the `MainFrame` class, nor should it.

The instance in that main method goes out of scope as soon as the method exits and is garbage collected.

Why would the MainFrame class have a reference to a Test instance inside it?  Bad design.  It's called a [circular dependency](http://www.codepuz.com/2013/11/circular-dependency-anti-pattern-and.html).  Once you add it, you can never separate the two classes.  Sometimes they can't be helped, but I see no reason for it at all here, especially for a class named `Test`.  `Test` can know about `MainFrame`, but `MainFrame` need never know about `Test`.  You've done it wrong.

You don't need to extend `JFrame`.  You aren't adding anything by extending.  I'll bet this should be a `JPanel` that you'll add to a `JFrame`.

Comment: i know that the compiler doesn't  find the MainFrame instance,how i can fix it?

Comment: Better learn Java.  You don't understand a lick of it right now.

Comment: i want to be more clear, if i create a new instance of the MainFrame it will create a new frame.... and i don't want do to it...

Comment: Your problem is that MainFrame shouldn't extend JFrame, like I said.

Comment: in my main program i add a lot of things in my frame,what i post here it's only a little sample..

Comment: No, I sincerely doubt it.  Extending JFrame is likely to be a mistake.  You might need several JPanels in a layout, but you aren't changing the behavior of JFrame one bit.  You can use it without extending.

Answer (score 2):

In stead of advising about design, I'll just put a way to achieve it.

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    private Test test;

    public void setTest(Test test) {
        this.test = test;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Test {
    MainFrame mainFrame;

    public Test(MainFrame mainFrame) {
        this.mainFrame = mainFrame;
        this.mainFrame.setTest(this);
    }
}
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Quick fix for your NullPointerExceptions:

```
public class Test {
MainFrame mainFrame;
public void update(){
    mainFrame.setNumber(10);
}
public void setMainFrame(MainFrame mainFrame) {
    this.mainFrame = maninFrame;
}
```

In `initFrame()`:

```
test = new Test();
test.setMainFrame(this);
test.update();
```

Otherwise I agree, the concept you're trying has a lot of misunderstanding. Try to separate the `Test` and `MainFrame` logic.

Comment: in my program `mainFrame` and `test` are strictly closed, it is difficult to separate.